# p:carousel show only first and third slide

Tags: primefaces

I have a problem with primefaces carousel it show only 2 items of 5 , the first and the third only:

```
<p:carousel numVisible="0" style="height: 350px !important;width: 860px !important;;"  autoPlayInterval="4000" firstVisible="0" itemStyleClass="width:870px;height:350px;" circular="true">
    <p:panel styleClass="carousel-panel">
        <p:graphicImage width="877" height="350"  value="/home_page/Carr0.png" />
    </p:panel>   
    <p:panel styleClass="carousel-panel">
        <p:graphicImage width="877" height="350"  value="/home_page/Carr1.png" />
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="carousel-panel">
        <p:graphicImage width="877" height="350"  value="/home_page/Carr2.png" />
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="carousel-panel">
        <p:graphicImage width="877" height="350"  value="/home_page/Carr3.png" />
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="carousel-panel">
        <p:graphicImage width="877" height="350"  value="/home_page/Carr4.png" />
    </p:panel>
</p:carousel>
```

Comment: I'm sure it's not this but the images aren't possibly copies of each other are they?

Comment: what if you remove all the explicit widths or the invisible. And what is your version